# accurev revert to parent stream version

Tags: accurev

There are two Accurev streams, A and B.  B is the child of A.

Feature X was mistakenly ported into stream B at one point.   Some time later, this was noticed and it was decided to move feature X to another stream to correct the issue.  The transaction T for feature X was sent to another stream and reverted in stream B.

So far so good, but there were other files that became modified in stream B only in support of feature X.  The problem I'm having is that there seems to be no way of abandoning the version of an element in stream B and reverting to the parent stream A's version, as if the file had never been changed in stream B.  Trying to fix this by copying versions resulted in a big mess.

Is is possible to "revert to parent" for a file?

Comment: How did you revert the changes from stream B?  If you performed a "revert to basis" operation in stream B, you should have inherited the version from stream A.

Comment: There was a single transaction that brought the feature into stream B.  I selected that transaction from the stream history did a "revert" operation on it to back out the changes.

Comment: Ok, I got it.  Under the stream you can list the active element and select "revert to basis" for any of them.   That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!